# How to make multicolumns stretch over multirows in latex table without overshooting the page edges

Tags: longtable, multicolumn, multirow

I have a longtable and I want the top most row to span over multiple rows so that I can enter detailed description of the table without the text overlapping and disappearing over the edges of the borders.

How can I achieve this? I have tried the below and provide the current output that I get?

```
 \FloatBarrier
    \begin{longtable}[H]{|>{\RaggedRight}p{3.0cm}|p{9.7cm}|}
    \caption{Requirements \cite{ref-book-3-2}.\label{tab1}} 
    \hline
     \multicolumn{2}{|c|}{Here I put the detailed description of the table, and i want to stretch over multiple rows as there is a lot of text that must fit without overshooting the edge of the pages} \\
    \hline
    \textbf{Feature} & \textbf{Requirement}\\
    \hline
    One & Requirement 4 \\
    \hline
    Two & Requirement 4 \\
    \hline
    Three & Requirement 4 \\
    \hline
    Four & Requirement 4 \\
    \hline
    \end{longtable}
```

The output showing the top row not fitting the description within the width is shown here [image]

Comment: `\begin{longtable}[H]` longtable doesn't have an H option. for your long text use `\caption*` or use `p{..}` not `c` in the `\multicolumn` as in `tabular` a `c` entry is always single-line

Comment: Does the trick. Thanks David

Answer (score 1):

With new table package `tabullarray` is simple. Width of the multi-column cell can be  determined automatically by option `hspan=minimal`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
    \begin{longtblr}[caption={Requirements \cite{ref-book-3-2}},
                    \label={tab1}
                    ]%
                    {hlines, vlines,
                     hspan=minimal,     % <---
                     colspec={X[1,l] X[3,l]},
                     row{2} = {font=\bfseries}
                    }
\SetCell[c=2]{l}
    Here I put the detailed description of the table, and I want to stretch over multiple rows as there is a lot of text that must fit without overshooting the edge of the pages
        &                   \\
Feature &   Requirement     \\
One     &   Requirement 1   \\
Two     &   Requirement 2   \\
Three   &   Requirement 3   \\
Four    &   Requirement 4   \\
    \end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

It is easy to determine the exact value of the width of the `p` column for the table head:

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{ragged2e} 
\usepackage{array, longtable}
\setlength{\extrarowheight}{2pt}

\begin{document}

 \begin{longtable}{|>{\RaggedRight}p{3.0cm}|p{9.7cm}|}
\caption{Requirements \cite{ref-book-3-2}.\label{tab1}}\\
\hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| p{\dimexpr12.7cm + 2\tabcolsep + \arrayrulewidth}|}{Here I put the detailed description of the table, and I want to stretch over multiple rows as there is a lot of text that must fit without overshooting the edge of the pages} \\
\hline
\textbf{Feature} & \textbf{Requirement}\\
\hline
One & Requirement 4 \\
\hline
Two & Requirement 4 \\
\hline
Three & Requirement 4 \\
\hline
Four & Requirement 4 \\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @DavidCarlisle: That's right, but I'm  not sure a difference of 0.4pt is visible. However it'll be fixed within seconds. Thanks for remembering me!

Comment: I get the correct output but with error: "Package longtable Error: longtable not in 1-column mode". When I try to place the longtable between \onecolumn and \twocolumn, the error disappears bu the table is pushed to the far right of the page thereby cutting big part of the table and text. How can I ensure the table is not moved to the far right of the page.

Comment: @Gee: This was not mentioned in the post. A possible solution, if the article uses the ‘two-column’ option,  would be to nest the longtable in the `strip` environment, from the `cuted` package (`sttools` bundle).

Comment: Thanks I will try that. Correct, that was not mentioned in the original post. I only realized the error later but the output was okay.